# WPF Expander control header not rendering on XP machine

Tags: wpf, windows-xp, rendering

I have a WPF expander control which is not rendering the expander header content when the app is run on XP machine (XP with SP3), when run on a Win7 machine the content is rendered as expected.

The expander header is a virtualised stack panel (horizontal) with a couple of text blocks inside.

When I use snoop to investigate I can see the expected text and the font colour is black - so it's not white text on a white background.

Anyone know why it would not be rendering on XP?

Header template:

```
<Expander.Header>
   <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Controls2:HighlightTextBlock Style="{StaticResource RegularTextStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    HighlightText="{Binding RelativeSource=RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls2:ViewHost}}, Path=DataContext.SearchText}"
                                    Foreground="{StaticResource Jedi.HighlightForegroundTextBrush}"
                                    HighlightBackground="{StaticResource Jedi.HighlightBackgroundTextBrush}"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="15,0,0,0">
         <Run Text="(" />
         <Run Text="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
         <Run Text=")"/>
      </TextBlock>
   </VirtualizingStackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
```

Comment: Did you try using a StackPanel instead of the VirtualizingStackPanel

Comment: It works if you swap to a StackPanel

Comment: Added it as a detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the VirtualizingStackPanel by a StackPanel.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) :

> The word "virtualize" refers to a technique by which a subset of user
>   interface (UI) elements are generated from a larger number of data
>   items based on which items are visible on-screen. Generating many UI
>   elements when only a few elements might be on the screen can adversely
>   affect the performance of your application. The VirtualizingStackPanel
>   calculates the number of visible items and works with the
>   ItemContainerGenerator from an ItemsControl (such as ListBox or
>   ListView) to create UI elements only for visible items.

So in this case, as there are few items inside your panel, it is not needed.